# Lua - Calculating Primes from 1 to n

Tags: lua, primes

I am very new to Lua and am simply learning it through the mentors on my robotics team. They challenged us with the problem to print all the primes under 444. My attempt at this was:

```
isPrime = true

for i = 2, math.floor(math.sqrt(444)) do
     for n = 2, i-1 do
           if i % n == 0 then
                isPrime = false
           end
      end
if isPrime == true then
      print(i)
end
end
```

However, the program is only spitting back 2 and 3. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 4):

The loop prints out a number if `isPrime` is true, but `isPrime` gets set to `false` when you check the value `4`, and nothing ever sets it to true again.

---

Your program consists of an outer loop for each number you want to check, and an inner loop for checking that number.

That inner loop is designed such that for prime numbers it will not touch `isPrime`, and for composite numbers it will set `isPrime` to false. So for prime numbers the value of `isPrime` will be whatever it was set to before the inner loop began. Since you want `isPrime` to be `true` at the end for prime numbers, you should set `isPrime` to true just before the inner loop.

Once you do that your program still has a bug. Your algorithm is a little bit confused on where exactly `sqrt(n)` matters.

Some other advice:

Get used to using local variables, not globals. This will help avoid bugs where you accidentally reset variables that you don't intend to.

```
local isPrime = true
```

Use consistent indentation. It will help when anyone reads your code. In this case your `if isPrime == true then print(i) end` code is not indented enough.

You can skip the `== true` in an `if` condition: `if isPrime then print(i) end`.

---

There's a better algorithm for finding all the primes up to a certain value named the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Here's an implementation in Lua:

```
function sieve_of_eratosthenes(n)
  local is_prime = {}

  for i = 1, n do
    is_prime[i] = 1 ~= i
  end

  for i = 2, math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) do
    if is_prime[i] then
      for j = i*i, n, i do
        is_prime[j] = false
      end
    end
  end

  return is_prime
end
```

```
local primes = sieve_of_eratosthenes(444)

for key, value in pairs(primes) do
  if (value) then
    print(key)
  end
end
```